# "Amount" or "Amounts"?

Tags: grammaticality

My question is that which is the suitable and correct sentence related to the amount.

1) Sum of both amount?
OR
2) Sum of both amounts?

Kindly intimate concerning this and clarify the concept of mine ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

***The sum of both amounts***, certainly.

The word "both" is only used with pairs, and a pair is invariably plural. The plural of the word "amount" is "amounts."

Comment: I wonder why this answer was downvoted. It is a succinct answer to a simple question.

Comment: @Lawrence: Funny you should ask. I was just wondering the same thing.

Comment: +1 I suspect it was a drive-by downvote by whoever downvoted the question. (As with, I suspect, another answer of yours I just saw.)